# Postgres comparison same rows,count and match from 3 defferent tables

Tags: postgresql, comparison, rows

i have 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE product (
        productid int,
        name varchar(80),
        safetystocklevel int,
        reorderpoint int,
        standardcost int,
        listprice numeric,
        productcategoryid numeric
        );

CREATE TABLE salesorderdetail (
        salesorderid int,
        salesorderdetailid int,
        orderqty int,
        productid int,
        unitprice numeric,
        unitpricediscount numeric,
        linetotal numeric
        );

CREATE TABLE salesorderheader (
        salesorderid int,
        orderdate date,
        duedate date,
        shipdate date,
        onlineorderflag int,
        customerid int,
        creditcardid int,
        subtotal numeric,
        taxamt  numeric,
        freight numeric,
        totaldue numeric
        );
```

i want to know the clients who made an order witch contains at least 3 products from different categories

i think i should do something like :

```
SELECT saleorderid,productid FROM salesorderdetail WHERE lag(productid)!= productid AND lead(productid)!= productid AND lag(productid)!=lead(productid))

INTERSECT

(SELECT productid,productcategoryid FROM product WHERE lag(productcategoryid)!=productcategoryid AND lead(productcategoryid)!=productcategoryid AND lead(productcategoryid)!=lag(productcategoryid))
```

Comment: Three products from different categories in a **single** order or counted over all orders of the customer?

Comment: yes yes from a single order of a single customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
select distinct sh.customerid
from salesorderdetail sd
  join product p on p.productid = sd.productid
  join salesorderheader sh on sd.salesorderid = sh.salesorderid
group by sh.customerid, sh.salesorderid
having count(distinct p.productcategoryid) >= 3
```

Comment: so if i want to know the number of counts of a user[how many times he ordered products from 3 different categories] how could i count the counts?
obv i cant do
 'select distinct sh.customerid,count(count(distinct p.productcategoryid) >= 3)'